# How to iterate over rows of each column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

My current code functions and produces a graph if there is only 1 sensor, i.e. if col2, and col3 are deleted in the example data provided below, leaving one column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'col1': [-2587.944231, -1897.324231,-2510.304231,-2203.814231,-2105.734231,-2446.964231,-2963.904231,-2177.254231, 2796.354231,-2085.304231], 'col2': [-3764.468462,-3723.608462,-3750.168462,-3694.998462,-3991.268462,-3972.878462,3676.608462,-3827.808462,-3629.618462,-1841.758462,], 'col3': [-166.1357692,-35.36576923, 321.4157692,108.9257692,-123.2257692, -10.84576923, -100.7457692, 89.27423077, -211.0857692, 101.5342308]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
sensors = 3
window_size = 5
dfn = df.rolling(window_size).corr(pairwise = True)

index = df.index #index of values in the data frame.
rows = len(index) #len(index) returns number of rows in the data.
sensors = 3

baseline_num = [0]*(rows) #baseline numerator, by default zero
baseline = [0]*(rows) #initialize baseline value
baseline = DataFrame(baseline)
baseline_num = DataFrame(baseline_num)


v = [None]*(rows) # Initialize an empty array v[] equal to amount of rows in .csv file
s = [None]*(rows) #Initialize another empty array for the slope values for detecting when there is an exposure
d = [0]*(rows)

sensors_on = True #Is the sensor detecting something (True) or not (False).
off_count  = 0
off_require = 8 # how many offs until baseline is updated
sensitivity = 1000

for i in range(0, (rows)): #This iterates over each index value, i.e. each row, and sums the values and returns them in list format.

    v[i] = dfn.loc[i].to_numpy().sum() - sensors


for colname,colitems in df.iteritems():
    for rownum,rowitem in colitems.iteritems():

        #d[rownum] = dfone.loc[rownum].to_numpy()
        #d[colname][rownum] = df.loc[colname][rownum]

        if v[rownum] >= sensitivity:
            sensors_on = True
            off_count = 0
            baseline_num[rownum] = 0

        else:
            sensors_on = False
            off_count += 1
            if off_count == off_require:
                for x in range(0, (off_require)):
                    baseline_num[colname][rownum] += df[colname][rownum - x]

            elif off_count > off_require:
                baseline_num[colname][rownum] += baseline_num[colname][rownum - 1] + df[colname][rownum] - (df[colname][rownum - off_require]) #this loop is just an optimization, one calculation per loop once the first calculation is established

        baseline[colname][rownum] = ((baseline_num[colname][rownum])//(off_require)) #mean of the last "off_require" points



dfx = DataFrame(v, columns =['Sensor Correlation']) #converts the summed correlation tables back from list format to a DataFrame, with the sole column name 'Sensor Correlation'
dft = pd.DataFrame(baseline, columns =['baseline'])
dft = dft.astype(float)

dfx.plot(figsize=(50,25), linewidth=5, fontsize=40) # plots dfx dataframe which contains correlated and summed data
dft.plot(figsize=(50,25), linewidth=5, fontsize=40)
```

Basically, instead of 1 graph as this produces, I would like to iterate over each column only for this loop:

```
for colname,colitems in df.iteritems():
    for rownum,rowitem in colitems.iteritems():

        #d[rownum] = dfone.loc[rownum].to_numpy()
        #d[colname][rownum] = df.loc[colname][rownum]

        if v[rownum] >= sensitivity:
            sensors_on = True
            off_count = 0
            baseline_num[rownum] = 0

        else:
            sensors_on = False
            off_count += 1
            if off_count == off_require:
                for x in range(0, (off_require)):
                    baseline_num[colname][rownum] += df[colname][rownum - x]

            elif off_count > off_require:
                baseline_num[colname][rownum] += baseline_num[colname][rownum - 1] + df[colname][rownum] - (df[colname][rownum - off_require]) #this loop is just an optimization, one calculation per loop once the first calculation is established
```

I've tried some other solutions from other questions but none of them seem to solve this case.
As of now, I've tried multiple conversions to things like lists and tuples, and then calling them something like this:

```
baseline_num[i,column] += d[i - x,column]
```

as well as

```
baseline_num[i][column += d[i - x][column]
```

while iterating over the loop using

```
for column in columns
```

However no matter how I seem to arrange the solution, there is always some keyerror of expecting integer or slice indices, among other errors.
See pictures for expected/possible outputs of one column on actual data.with varying input parameters (sensitivity value, and off_require is varied in different cases.)
One such solution which didn't work was the looping method from this link:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterating-over-rows-and-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/

I've also tried creating a loop using iteritems as the outer loop. This did not function as well.

Below are links to possible graph outputs for various sensitivity values, and windows in my actual dataset, with only one column. (i.e i manually deleted other columns, and plotted just the one using the current program)

[sensitivity 1000, window 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fRAZ.png)

[sensitivity 800, window 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkHnW.png)

[sensitivity 1500, window 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lvBL.png)

If there's anything I've left out that would be helpful to solving this, please let me know so I can rectify it immediately.

See this picture for my original df.head:
[df.head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb3xW.png)

Comment: there is too much code here and too much logic, please provide a minimal reproducible example otherwise you won't get any help unfortunately

Comment: ok thanks. Ill try to do that just looking over it I'm not sure what I could leave out to make a smaller example. This is already a "small" functional excerpt of my original functional code. I will try to figure out a way to make a smaller example like you've said though.

Comment: this code does not run. `NameError: name 'dfone' is not defined` line 37

Comment: sorry. dfone is the line for running it for one graph. The commented out line below it is the one meant for running multiple at once. I've edited the code to remove the dfone line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try,

```
for colname,colitems in df.iteritems():
    for rownum,rowitem in colitems.iteritems():
        print(df[colname][rownum])
```

The first loop iterates over all the columns, and the 2nd loops iterates over all the rows for that column.

edit:

From our conversation below, I think that your baseline and df dataframes don't have the same column names because of how you created them and how you are accessing the elements.

My suggestion is that you create the baseline dataframe to be a copy of your df dataframe and edit the information within it from there.

Edit:

I have managed to make your code work for 1 loop, but I run into an index error, I am not sure what your optimisation function does but i think that is what is causing it, take a look.

It is this part `baseline_num[colname][rownum - 1]`, in the second loop i guess because you do rownum (0) -1, you get index -1. You need to change it so that in the first loop rownum is 1 or something, I am not sure what you are trying to do there.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'col1': [-2587.944231, -1897.324231,-2510.304231,-2203.814231,-2105.734231,-2446.964231,-2963.904231,-2177.254231, 2796.354231,-2085.304231], 'col2': [-3764.468462,-3723.608462,-3750.168462,-3694.998462,-3991.268462,-3972.878462,3676.608462,-3827.808462,-3629.618462,-1841.758462,], 'col3': [-166.1357692,-35.36576923, 321.4157692,108.9257692,-123.2257692, -10.84576923, -100.7457692, 89.27423077, -211.0857692, 101.5342308]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
sensors = 3
window_size = 5
dfn = df.rolling(window_size).corr(pairwise = True)

index = df.index #index of values in the data frame.
rows = len(index) #len(index) returns number of rows in the data.
sensors = 3

baseline_num = [0]*(rows) #baseline numerator, by default zero
baseline = [0]*(rows) #initialize baseline value
baseline = pd.DataFrame(df)
baseline_num = pd.DataFrame(df)
#print(baseline_num)


v = [None]*(rows) # Initialize an empty array v[] equal to amount of rows in .csv file
s = [None]*(rows) #Initialize another empty array for the slope values for detecting when there is an exposure
d = [0]*(rows)

sensors_on = True #Is the sensor detecting something (True) or not (False).
off_count  = 0
off_require = 8 # how many offs until baseline is updated
sensitivity = 1000

for i in range(0, (rows)): #This iterates over each index value, i.e. each row, and sums the values and returns them in list format.

    v[i] = dfn.loc[i].to_numpy().sum() - sensors


for colname,colitems in df.iteritems():
    #print(colname)
    for rownum,rowitem in colitems.iteritems():
        #print(rownum)
        #display(baseline[colname][rownum])
        #d[rownum] = dfone.loc[rownum].to_numpy()
        #d[colname][rownum] = df.loc[colname][rownum]

        if v[rownum] >= sensitivity:
            sensors_on = True
            off_count = 0
            baseline_num[rownum] = 0

        else:
            sensors_on = False
            off_count += 1
            if off_count == off_require:
                for x in range(0, (off_require)):
                    baseline_num[colname][rownum] += df[colname][rownum - x]

            elif off_count > off_require:
                baseline_num[colname][rownum] += baseline_num[colname][rownum - 1] + df[colname][rownum] - (df[colname][rownum - off_require]) #this loop is just an optimization, one calculation per loop once the first calculation is established

        baseline[colname][rownum] = ((baseline_num[colname][rownum])//(off_require)) #mean of the last "off_require" points

        print(baseline[colname][rownum])


dfx = pd.DataFrame(v, columns =['Sensor Correlation']) #converts the summed correlation tables back from list format to a DataFrame, with the sole column name 'Sensor Correlation'
dft = pd.DataFrame(baseline, columns =['baseline'])
dft = dft.astype(float)

dfx.plot(figsize=(50,25), linewidth=5, fontsize=40) # plots dfx dataframe which contains correlated and summed data
dft.plot(figsize=(50,25), linewidth=5, fontsize=40)
```

My output looks like this,

```
-324.0
-238.0
-314.0
-276.0
-264.0
-306.0
-371.0
-806.0
638.0
-412.0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    354                 try:
--> 355                     return self._range.index(new_key)
    356                 except ValueError as err:

ValueError: -1 is not in range


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    355                     return self._range.index(new_key)
    356                 except ValueError as err:
--> 357                     raise KeyError(key) from err
    358             raise KeyError(key)
    359         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

KeyError: -1
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the best solution, however, the error that arises when using this solution is that my arrays often expect only one index, when I need to have a row and column index (i.e ``` d[row][column] ). Similarly, they expect int values for column, while iteritems seems to be returning the column names. I'm not sure why this is, as the example you've provided works perfectly and shouldnt be different in that respect.

Comment: you are supposed to do df[column][row] i think, what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: hey @ultruction look at the solution i just posted, i think that might be what you are looking for, it accesses each item using the column name followed by the index number.

Comment: Hey that seems to be getting somewhere. The only error I get when running that is: KeyError: 'S1(scaa)' from line ```baseline[colname][rownum] = ((baseline_num[colname][rownum])//(off_require))``` This suggests maybe it's expecting baseline and baseline_num to have the same colnames in order to function? Unsure.

Comment: Fixed now. See above comment important to mention ive already changed baseline and baseline_num to dataframes.

Comment: can you update your code with the full changes youve made so i can see the error myself.

Comment: did you make the loops like it did before using the variables ?

Comment: Code has been updated. Not sure if I understand the second question. Wish I could move this to chat but not enough reputation, sorry!

Comment: can you print a copy of the dataframe (df) you made, because it seems like there is an error with it.

Comment: i think i know what it is, your column names in df and baseline dont match

Comment: I posted an imgur link to my df.head, its worth noting s1(scaa) is my first column, compared to "col1" in my reproducible example code. Sorry for not catching that and mentioning it earlier.

Comment: if your baseline dataframe is the same shape as your df dataframe, just make it an exact copy, and iterate over it

Comment: I have updated my answer, I am not sure what your code is doing during the for loop but I managed to make it run properly once after making the dataframes the same (length, size, columnnames and content). As you can see I run into an index error, I think it is how you are running your optimisation code. You need to change the part that minus 1 from row num because 0 - 1 is -1 and there is no row indexed -1

Comment: I see. Im not sure how that happens because that code only runs when "off_count" is greater than a set value, i.e it should never be less than 5, let alone be equal to 0. Upon commenting the optimisation out, and changing the above to: ``` if off_count == off_require:
                for x in range(0, (off_require)):
                    baseline_num[colname][rownum] += df[colname][rownum - x] ``` It functions, however only when off_count == off_require. When changing the loop to ``` if off_count >= off_require:``` I get the same error as when I use the "optimisation" line, of accessing -1.

Comment: yeah i think thats another question altogether, i hope i have answered you question on how to iterate over the rows, if its correct please mark my answer as the right answer, you should post another question which is more detailed about your loop itself if you want help figuring it out, i am guessing its how you designed your loop that is causing the issue.

Comment: I think you're right. Thanks a ton i'll accept the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but below is what I was able to work out.  Hope it helps!

I tried to use the `to_list()` function while working out an answer, and it threw me an error:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_list'`

So, I decided to circumvent that method and came up with this:

```
indexes = [x for x in df.index]

row_vals = []

for index in indexes :
    for val in df.iloc[i].values:
        row_vals.append(val)
```

The object `row_vals` will contain all values in row order.

If you only want to get the row values for a particular row or set of rows, you would need to do this:

```
indx_subset = [`list of row indices`] #(Ex. [1, 2, 5, 6, etc...])

row_vals = []

for indx in indx_subset:
    for val in df.loc[indx].values:
        row_vals.append(val)
```

`row_vals` will then have all the row values from the specified indices.